# How would I make this a working update Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My Query is updating two different tables at once. I'd like to know how would I make this a working update query I'm new in MySQL so I don't know what to do thank you

Here is my query

```
$sSQLupdate = "UPDATE settings SET companyName = '$companyname', 
                                            companyAddress = '$companyaddress', 
                                            companyContact = '$companycontact', 
                                            excessot1 = '$excessot1', 
                                            multiplierOT1 = '$multiplier1', 
                                            excessot2 = '$excessot2', 
                                            multiplierOT2 = '$multiplier2', 
                                            ndRangeFrom = '$ND_in',
                                            ndRangeTo = '$ND_out',
                                            multiplierNd = '$NDmul'
                                            WHERE id = 1"; 


"UPDATE holidaytype SET multiplier = '$regularmul'  WHERE type = 'Regular'";
"UPDATE holidaytype SET multiplier = '$specialrmul'  WHERE type = 'Special'";
"UPDATE holidaytype SET multiplier = '$doubleregularmul'  WHERE type = 'DRegular'";
"UPDATE holidaytype SET multiplier = '$doublespecialmul'  WHERE type = 'DSpecial'";
```

Php Codes are here it is just how I get the values from the input textbox:

```
            $companyname = $this->input->get('companyname');
        $companyaddress = $this->input->get('companyaddress');
        $companycontact = $this->input->get('companycontact');
        $excessot1 = $this->input->get('excessot1');
        $multiplier1 = $this->input->get('multiplier1');
        $excessot2 = $this->input->get('excessot2');
        $multiplier2 = $this->input->get('multiplier2');
        $ND_in = $this->input->get('NDfrom');
        $ND_out = $this->input->get('NDto');
        $NDmul = $this->input->get('NDmul');
        $regularmul =  $this->input->get('regularmulti');
        $specialmul =  $this->input->get('specialmulti');
        $doubleregularmul =  $this->input->get('doubleregmulti');
        $doublespecialmul =  $this->input->get('doublespecialmul');
        $restdaymul1 =  $this->input->get('restmul1');
        $restdaymul2 =  $this->input->get('restmul2');
        $restdaymul3 =  $this->input->get('restmul3');
        $restdaymul4 =  $this->input->get('restmul4');
```

Comment: It seems you are using PHP. Can you also post your code using these variables and sql statements?

Comment: @user340341: Post code that your wrote on executing sql statements. Which part of the SQL statement are you struck with? What change are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sSQLupdate = "UPDATE settings SET companyName = '" . $companyname . "', 
                                   companyAddress = '" . $companyaddress . "', 
                                   companyContact = '" . $companycontact . "', 
                                   excessot1 = '" . $excessot1 . "', 
                                   multiplierOT1 = '" . $multiplier1 . "', 
                                   excessot2 = '" . $excessot2 . "', 
                                   multiplierOT2 = '" . $multiplier2 . "', 
                                   ndRangeFrom = '" . $ND_in . "',
                                   ndRangeTo = '" . $ND_out . "',
                                   multiplierNd = '" . $NDmul . "'
                                   WHERE id = 1";
```